# tornado Periodiccallback and socket operations inside callback

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, tornado, nonblocking, periodic-task

I am trying to make a non-blocking web-application which uses Tornado.
That application uses PeriodicCallback as a scheduler for grabbing the data from news sites:

```
for nc_uuid in self.LIVE_NEWSCOLLECTORS.keys():
            self.LIVE_NEWSCOLLECTORS[nc_uuid].agreggator,ioloop=args
            period=int(self.LIVE_NEWSCOLLECTORS[nc_uuid].period)*60
            if self.timer is not None: period = int(self.timer)

            #self.scheduler.add_job(func=self.LIVE_NEWSCOLLECTORS[nc_uuid].getNews,args=[self.source,i],trigger='interval',seconds=10,id=nc_uuid)
            task = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(lambda:self.LIVE_NEWSCOLLECTORS[nc_uuid].getNews(self.source,i),1000*10,ioloop)
            task.start()
```

'getData' which is calling as a callback has an async http request that parses and sent data to TCPServer for analyzing by calling method process_responce:

```
@gen.coroutine 
def process_response(self,*args,**kwargs):
buf = {'sentence':str('text here')}
data_string = json.dumps(buf)
s.send(data_string)
while True:
    try:
         data = s.recv(100000)
         if not data:
                print "connection closed"
                s.close()
                break
         else:
             print "Received %d bytes: '%s'" % (len(data), data)
            # s.close()
             break
    except socket.error, e:
          if e.args[0] == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
               print 'error',errno.EWOULDBLOCK
               time.sleep(1)           # short delay, no tight loops
          else:
               print e
               break
    i+=1
```

Inside process_response I use basic example for non-blocking socket operations. 
Process_response shows something like this:
error 10035
error 10035
Received 75 bytes: '{"mode": 1, "keyword": "\u0435\u0432\u0440\u043e", "sentence": "text here"}'

That looks normal behavior. But when recieving data the main IOLoop are being locked! If I would ask webserver it wouldn`t return my anydata until periodiccallback task finishes...
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep()` is a blocking function and must never be used in non-blocking code. Use `yield gen.sleep()` instead.

Also consider using `tornado.iostream.IOStream` instead of raw socket operations.